# Python: ImportError: No module named 'HTMLParser'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have tried to ran this code but I am getting an error message for ImportError: No module named 'HTMLParser'. I am using Python 3.x. Any reason why this is not working ?

```
#Import the HTMLParser model
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

#Create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

#Function to handle the processing of HTML comments
    def handle_comment(self,data):
        print ("Encountered comment: ", data)
        pos = self.getpos()
        print ("At line: ", pos[0], "position ", pos[1])

def main():
    #Instantiate the parser and feed it some html
    parser= MyHTMLParser()

    #Open the sample file and read it
    f = open("myhtml.html")
    if f.mode== "r":
        contents= f.read()  #read the entire FileExistsError
        parser.feed()


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bm250199\workspace\test\htmlparsing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
ImportError: No module named 'HTMLParser'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html - "The HTMLParser module has been renamed to html.parser in Python 3"

Answer (score 66):

The module is called [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) in Python 3. So you need to change your import to reflect that new name:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

You should always check the [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) to make sure that you are importing the right things from the right location.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it overcome that issue. however, I am getting the following message now:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bm250199\workspace\test\htmlparsing.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\bm250199\workspace\test\htmlparsing.py", line 22, in main
    parser.feed()
TypeError: feed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Comment: Again, [check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.feed) and read the error message: You need to pass data to `parser.feed()`.

Comment: Working fine when adding data to the parser.feed. Thanks

Comment: Update as of 3.5, you will get a deprecation warning using this: `The unescape method is deprecated and will be removed in 3.5, use html.unescape() instead.` Now it's just `from html import unescape` and `escaped_text = unescape(original_text)`

Comment: @Brendan Are you sure you commented on the right question? This is about the HTML parser, and not about an unescape function.

Comment: @ Ha yes, I totally commented on the wrong question. Whoops!

Comment: @Brendan's comment helped me though. ;)